# Settings reset every time laptop is restarted

Tags: system-settings, reset

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 13.10, and my settings always reset every time I restart my laptop!

For example, Clementine library is back to empty, default browser is back to Firefox, etc. I need to set my browser to Chrome every I turn on my laptop. I'm a web developer and this is so annoying.

I have tried several ways like using Ubuntu Tweak to set default browser. But it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

This can have multiple reasons.

1. Did you migrate from a different Ubuntu/Linux installation?
2. Is the content of your home directoy, especially the config files and everything in .config/ still there when you restarted?

   ls -al $HOME

   ls -al $HOME/.config
3. Is your $HOME directory or /home mount point write protected or belongs to a different user? Check via, if everything is marked as rw.

   mount

> => /dev/mapper/vgpool-home on /home type ext4 (**rw**,relatime,data=ordered)

```
ls -al $HOME
```

> drwx------ 42 **YOUR_USERNAME** YOUR_USERNAME   4096 Apr 17 08:09 .config

```
ls -al /home
```

Comment: 1. nope, 2. yup, still there, 3. yup, everything is marked as "rw", and this "drwx------ 33 shaban shaban  4096 Apr 16 07:38 .config". then this: "drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root    4096 Apr  4 07:35 .", "drwxr-xr-x 24 root   root    4096 Apr 13 21:49 ..", "drwx------  2 root   root   16384 Apr  4 07:29 lost+found", "drwxr-xr-x 30 shaban shaban  4096 Apr 18 19:00 shaban".