# Settings reset to default every time I reboot

Tags: system-settings, reset

Every time I log in or reboot my system, the Ubuntu settings reset to what they were when I first installed the system. For example, the icons on the left-side launcher change to LibreText, Firefox, Amazon, etc... The icons that were there when first booted from an install CD. My display settings change to something unbearable that I have to change every time I log in.

Can anybody offer any help? I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448939/settings-reset-every-time-laptop-is-restarted) but it wasn't good.

Thanks a bunch,
Michael

Comment: Are you sure you are not booting up from the USB stick each time you turn on your PC? Sorry if it seems like a silly question but it is what came to my mind.

Comment: Heya hakermania, thanks for the reply. I am not. In fact, I never could figure that out... I just burned a DVD to install Ubuntu. And before you ask, I'm not booting from the DVD either, lol.